# For a Schwartz function $f(x,y)$, is $f(x+y,y)$ also a Schwartz function?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, schwartz-space

The question is as in the title. This seems intuitively clear but I cannot see how to prove rigorously. Let me phrase more precisely:

For a Schwartz function $f(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, is the function $g(x,y)$ defined as $g(x,y):=f(x+y,y)$ also a Schwartz function?

The linear combination $x+y$ in the first argument seems of some concern for me.. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Show that if $f$ is Schwartz, then so is $f \circ A$ for A an invertible matrix.